# Django Oracle integrity error when saving any instance to database

Tags: sql, django, oracle, django-models, ora-01400

I'm doing a migration from sqlite to oracle backend. The oracle database already exists and is maintained by other people. Its version is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.1.0.

I have a simple model:

```
class AliasType(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="F_ALIAS_ID")
    name = models.CharField(u"Type name", max_length=255, unique=True, db_column="F_ALIAS_NAME")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "ALIAS"
```

`./manage.py syncdb` does not return any errors. But when I try to create a new instance and save it to the database, I get the following error:

```
>>> AliasType.objects.create(name="test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/Data/private/projects/envs/termary-oracle/src/django/django/db/models/manager.py", line 138, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "/mnt/Data/private/projects/envs/termary-oracle/src/django/django/db/models/query.py", line 360, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/mnt/Data/private/projects/envs/termary-oracle/src/django/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/mnt/Data/private/projects/envs/termary-oracle/src/django/django/db/models/base.py", line 553, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
  File "/mnt/Data/private/projects/envs/termary-oracle/src/django/django/db/models/manager.py", line 195, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/Data/private/projects/envs/termary-oracle/src/django/django/db/models/query.py", line 1435, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/mnt/Data/private/projects/envs/termary-oracle/src/django/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 791, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/mnt/Data/private/projects/envs/termary-oracle/src/django/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 735, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/Data/private/projects/envs/termary-oracle/src/django/django/db/backends/util.py", line 18, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/Data/private/projects/envs/termary-oracle/src/django/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 630, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
IntegrityError: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SINCE"."ALIAS"."F_ALIAS_ID")
```

If I specify id, e.g. `AliasType.objects.create(id=5, name="test")`, it works. I thought django should be able to retrieve id value automatically. I've learnt that Oracle does not support autoincrement, and I should use triggers and sequences. I was told that there is an existing sequence in the database that returns ids for all new rows, and I know its name, say `SEQ_GET_NEW_ID`.

So the question is how to implement that in the most elegant way, i.e. how to tell Django to `get id values for all new objects from the sequence named SEQ_GET_NEW_ID` without hacking it too much (e.g. overriding save() methods for all models)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ticket open ([#1946](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1946)) to allow exactly that, overriding the default sequence name. But as it's not closed yet, I don't think there is a way without hacking.

I haven't used Oracle before, but a quick search suggests that it is possible to create aliases/synonyms for sequences. `manage.py sqlall <app>` should show you the sequence name Django is expecting. So you probably could just make this an alias for `SEQ_GET_NEW_ID`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped my find a workaround. I asked the person who maintain the database to create triggers for all tables. The triggers get next id before insertion from the same sequence `SEQ_GET_NEW_ID`. So aliases for sequence were not needed here.

Comment: Just to clarify things about how django gets the id of the row just inserted. 
If the option `use_returning_into` is specified, django gets the id directly from the `INSERT` clause. In this case sequence is not needed by django. 
If `use_returning_into` is false, django first gets a new id from the sequence that has a name `APP_MODEL_SQ` and then inserts the row with that id. In this case you need to create aliases for existing sequences (it can be the same sequence for the whole database) so that django will be able to use them.